# How to print to standard output from multiple threads using POCO in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, cout, poco-libraries

I want to create a simple program that starts 5 threads that print "hello world! This is thread [thread number]".

Each print operation should be preceded by a random wait operation, to demonstrate that the threads are running concurrently. (The threads will print their message in a random order, as opposed to printing in order which would happen if the threads are running sequentially.)

Here is the code that should achieve this:

```
Poco::Thread thread[5];

class HelloRunnable: public Poco::Runnable
{
public:
    HelloRunnable(int arg)
    {
        n = arg;
    }

    int n;

    virtual void run()
    {
        usleep(rand()%100000);
        std::cout << "Hello, world! This is thread " << n << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        HelloRunnable runnable(i);
        thread[i].start(runnable);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        thread[i].join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, at run time, this gives the error:

```
//pure virtual method called
//terminate called without an active exception
//The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

If instead, I put `thread[i].join()` inside the same for loop as `thread[i].start()`, then the program runs without error but it prints the threads in order. (Becuase `join()` waits until the thread has finished before moving on, hence the threads are executed sequentially and not concurrently.

How can I make the threads run concurrently and print out the message to the standard output as soon as `cout` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you create the objects inside the for loop their lifetime will end immediately after each iteration. This will cause issues. As the [documentation](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Thread.html) for `start()` states:

> Note that the given Runnable object must remain valid during the entire lifetime of the thread, as only a reference to it is stored internally.

You need to create the runnables in a way that keeps them alive outside the loop also.

Comment: Thanks, This was one of the problems with my code. I have now fixed the issue. I removed the for loops and typed each line out explicitly. I also removed a thread as I can only run 4 threads without causing a crash. Finally, I created a separate runnable for each thread, as in the original code each thread was using the same one.

Answer (score 0):

As Sami has said, the runnable was destroyed before the thread had finished. I removed the for loops and typed each line out explicitly. I also removed a thread as I can only run 4 threads without causing a crash. Finally, I created a separate runnable for each thread, as in the original code each thread was using the same one.

```
Poco::Thread thread[5];

class HelloRunnable: public Poco::Runnable
{
public:
    HelloRunnable(int arg)
    {
        n = arg;
    }

    int n;

    virtual void run()
    {
        //sleep for random length of time
        timeval t;
        gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
        srand(t.tv_usec * t.tv_sec);
        int uS = rand()%100000;
        usleep(uS);

        //print message
        std::cout << "Hello, world! This is thread " << n << " I slept for "<< uS << "uS" <<std::endl;
        return;
    }
};



int main()
{
    HelloRunnable runnable1(1);
    thread[1].start(runnable1);

    HelloRunnable runnable2(2);
    thread[2].start(runnable2);

    HelloRunnable runnable3(3);
    thread[3].start(runnable3);

    HelloRunnable runnable4(4);
    thread[4].start(runnable4);

    thread[1].join();
    thread[2].join();
    thread[3].join();
    thread[4].join();

    return 0;
}
```